# How to change local notification icon?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart

I made the local notification icon with png file. However, in android, the icon looks transparent. It looks good in ios app. How can I show the original icon image as a notification icon?

ios notification icon
[image]

android notification icon
[image]

Notification code

```
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
// import 'package:timezone/data/latest_all.dart' as tz;
// import 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz;

final notifications = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

initNotification() async {

  var androidSetting = const AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');

  var iosSetting = const IOSInitializationSettings(
    requestAlertPermission: true,
    requestBadgePermission: true,
    requestSoundPermission: true,
  );

  var initializationSettings = InitializationSettings(
      android: androidSetting,
      iOS: iosSetting
  );
  await notifications.initialize(
    initializationSettings,
  );
}

showNotification() async {

  var androidDetails = const AndroidNotificationDetails(
    'ID',
    'notification',
    priority: Priority.high,
    importance: Importance.max,
    // color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 0, 0),
  );

  var iosDetails = const IOSNotificationDetails(
    presentAlert: true,
    presentBadge: true,
    presentSound: true,
  );

  notifications.show(
      1,
      'title1',
      'content1',
      NotificationDetails(android: androidDetails, iOS: iosDetails)
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you already changed the image for iOS?

Answer (score 5):

I have the same problem today. For android, you need to change the icon,
android -> app -> main -> res -> drawable and that name put inside

`var androidSetting = const AndroidInitializationSettings('ic_launcher');`

inside but for iOS I don't know where to change

Comment: Yes! That's exactly what I did. But didn't work :(

Answer (score 4):

1. You need an image with a transparent background
2. Put the image inside `android/app/src/main/res/drawable`. Ex: `notification.png`
3. Set the image configuration

```html
const androidSetting = AndroidInitializationSettings('notification');
```

where `notification` is the name of the image you put inside the `drawable` directory without the extension `.png`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use png image color, and it will show color icon on notification.

ex :
image file ic_launcher.png

create new file in your drawable folder

launcher_notification.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="fill" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
    <item>
        <bitmap android:gravity="center" android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and put "launcher_notification" in

```
var androidSetting = const AndroidInitializationSettings('launcher_notification');
```

if it show grey icon on emulator, try it on your phone. It's same if you want to use it for firebase notification icon

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, I just change the icon in the `@mipmap` files and keep the same name as `ic_launcher`. The code does the rest. It's a lazy approach but prevents you from an big headache

Answer (score 0):

If your notification Icon is displaying a grey or white color, check if the image you are using is transparent.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving it here as reference for iOS: this is how to do with flutter_local_notifications as per the package author

https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/issues/1870

> A reminder that documented in the readme
> (https://github.com/MaikuB/flutter_local_notifications/tree/master/flutter_local_notifications#example-app)
> is there's an example app. This shows basically every feature of the
> plugin including attachments on iOS/macOS. There isn't an ability to
> provide a different icon for each notification though you can
> associate a different, additional image. You can check this out
> through said app.
>
> General note that you should have an understanding of how the APIs
> work on your target platform and how these platforms work. Once you
> start from there then you look at what the plugin exposes as the
> plugin's purpose is to provide access to the native APIs. Anything
> outside of that is something you need to look into yourself. For
> example, Apple's documentation talks about how it's possible to have
> custom UI for a notification. Potentially this is what you can use for
> having a custom icon for each notification but isn't something
> supported by the plugin and an area that you would need to do further
> research on